# How do I properly use my SQLite db in my asp.net core 3.1 MVC application using EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-identity

So I'm trying to create a ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application which uses **Identity** and it's working well so far.
I wanted to add a SQLite db to it so I can store users etc using EF (EntityFramework) Code First and this is what I did.

I first created a database file using SQLite, so I have the Database.db file in a folder on my desktop.

I then tried finding documentations regarding how to implement it, but there were so many and all of them are very different so I couldn't pinpoint what would be the proper way of implementing it.

I started by setting up my Context

```
public class UserContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string SubscriptionID { get; set; }

    public int IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Super straight forward, and then I modified my ConfigureServices method which is in my Startup.cs to `AddIdentity`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserContext>();

}
```

Perfect, now I have Identity added. Great.

Here is the issue, I wanted to be able to create a initial migration to create a table in my database.db file but I have no idea where to put the connectionString and how to access it.

I read on some forums that I should store it inside appsettings.json, but what would the connectionString then look like since it's a file on my disk?

I do not believe that this would work

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "sqlConnection": "Server=C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\user\\Database\\Database.db;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;\\\""
  }
```

or is that what the connectionString should look like?

How do I properly implement the SQLite database file to my project so that I can access and create my first migration?

I also didn't find a way to create the database.db file with a password when creating it, is this possible to change?

Answer (score 17):

By following the below steps, the Sqlite Database will be created.

- Remove `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` Nuget Package, as you are not using SqlServer
- Add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` Nuget Package
- Change DefaultConnection in `appsettings.json` to:

> `"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=UserDatabase.db"`

- Delete the **Migrations** folder. (**Note:** The Migrations folder should not be deleted when you have deployed your database and upgrade your Table structure.)
- Open Package Manager Console and run: `add-migration MigrationName`
- Open Package Manager Console and run: `update-database`

**If you have problems running the commands in Package Manager:**
You can run the same commands in a terminal window using the dotnet command, just note that it will create a Migrations folder in whichever folder you run the command in:

- dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName
- dotnet ef database update

The Sqlite Database will be created.

> I also didn't find a way to create the database.db file with a password when creating it, is this possible to change?

1. Remove package `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`
2. Add package `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core`
3. Add package `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher`
4. Change DefaultConnection in `appsettings.json` to:

> `"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=UserDatabase.db;Password=ComplexPassword"`

Refer [SQLite doesn't support encrypting database files by default.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/encryption?tabs=netcore-cli) for more info.

Comment: In startup.cs don't forget to change UseSqlServer to UseSqlite : eg services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

Answer (score 0):

I recommended starting by placing your db file in the same directory as the project you are working on. Read the EF Core [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli) from microsoft docs, they use sqllite in that example.